# Как избавиться от переноса строки в выводе при парсинге?

Tags: python, парсер, web-scraping

Пишу парсер, код следующий:

```html
soup= BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
task_name= soup.find('h2', class_ = 'task__title').get_text()
print(task_name)
```

При выводе выходит это:

[image: ****]

Пытался удалять `/n`, все равно не помогает.

Как избавиться от отступа между строками?

Код сайта такой:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

заменить двойной перенос строк одинрным, возможно пустая строка имеет пробел тогда его добавить в условие

```
result.replace('\n\n','\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

добавьте *strip=True* в *get_text()*

```
get_text(strip=True)
```